# Unable to reformat an SSD from Ext4 to any other filesystem

Tags: boot, partitioning, permissions, ssd, disk-formatting

Any attempt to reformat said SSD just doesn't work. I used to run Linux Mint on it but a couple months ago the OS crashed and wouldn't open past the mint logo screen then some error messages.

I'm now trying to reformat that SSD externally and nothing works. In Windows, diskpart and disk management don't do anything. When I try formatting it to NTFS it turns right back to Ext4 after the process is complete. I can't delete any of the partitions and no OS will install on it because booting any OS also can't get past the partition stage as it won't be modified.

Running tests shows that the SSD is still healthy and in a DVD boot of mint I can still see my files and use them.

I'm currently on Ubuntu and wanted to use it for external storage. I don't know if the problem has anything to do with permissions or not. Using GParted or the disks utility doesn't work as I can't create new partitions, delete them or format them because even if it shows the format has been completed the partition will go back to Ext4.

Comment: What you describe strongly suggests that the device is not writable, possibly due to defects or damage that caused the crash in the first place. There is little use for such a storage device.

Comment: If you try to do this with GParted don’t forget you have to “Apply” the changes. If you do this what errors does GParted report?